# Interaction or assignment of struct variable to memory location

Tags: c, microcontroller

Please explain the following snippet of code from the microcontroller header file and how the structure variable is assigning to particular memory location indicated in code (i.e. 0x40000000 + 0x04000 = 0x40004000). And how can application programmer can access structure members and write into them indicated in the structure (i.e. IR, TCR, TC, PR, PC and MCR).

```
/*------------- Timer (TIM) --------------------------------------------------*/
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t IR; /* __IO is volatile read and write */
  __IO uint32_t TCR;
  __IO uint32_t TC;
  __IO uint32_t PR;
  __IO uint32_t PC;
  __IO uint32_t MCR;
} LPC_TIM_TypeDef;

#define LPC_APB0_BASE         (0x40000000UL)
#define LPC_TIM0_BASE         (LPC_APB0_BASE + 0x04000)
#define LPC_TIM0              ((LPC_TIM_TypeDef *) LPC_TIM0_BASE)
```

Comment: this is elementary C what part of this is confusing?  please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

As you have correctly stated, the `LPC_APB0_BASE` and `LPC_TIM0_BASE` macros, together, define the address of where the data for (presumably) "Timer 0" are located. The macro `LPC_TIM0` evaluates to a *pointer* to a `LPC_TIM_TypeDef` structure at that location.

So, in order to access members of that structure, you can use the `->` operator on `LPC_TIM0`; for example, to set the `TC` member, use code like this:

```c
uint32_t value = 123; // or whatever
LPC_TIM0->TC = value;
```

To read data from the `PC` member, use this:

```c
uint32_t value = LPC_TIM0->PC;
```

Fee free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like memory-mapped hardware registers.

If you define a struct in `C`, how would you access it by pointer?

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
} Moo;

Moo myMooStruct;
Moo *ptr = &myMooStruct;
ptr->x = 1;
```

Same applies here, except you have hardcoded address of the struct, which is `LPC_TIM0`.

```
LPC_TIM_TypeDef *timer = LPC_TIM0;
timer->IR = /* someValueHere */ 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Adrian Mole and @Tarek Dakhran for your help and I have re-written the above original code without typedef qualifier and define macros. Is my understanding correct and now I can easily access the structure members using LPC_TIM0->IR etc. And it is purely of my difficult in understanding of typedef and macros.

And based on this code, LPC_TIM0 will be pointer to a struct LPC_TIM_TypeDef and the structure is mapped to physical memory location 0x40004000.

```
/*------------- Timer (TIM) --------------------------------------------------*/

struct LPC_TIM_TypeDef
{
  __IO uint32_t IR; /* __IO is volatile read and write */
  __IO uint32_t TCR;
  __IO uint32_t TC;
  __IO uint32_t PR;
  __IO uint32_t PC;
  __IO uint32_t MCR;
};

struct LPC_TIM_TypeDef *LPC_TIM0 = ((struct LPC_TIM_TypeDef *) 0x40004000);
```

Comment: You shoud'nt rewrite the header supplied with your controller.

Comment: Thanks @Mike for your suggestion and I just want to understand the code written is correct or not. Because still i am learner and don't want to messy the header file supplied by microcontroller supplier because it will have other important structures linked to it.